# Designing NoSql database for smart device management system

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am trying to design no sql database for smart heating devices tenement house monitoring system. The building has one main heating system that provides heating to each apartment by tracking temperature in the apartment. For that reason each apartment has a thermometer which sends a temperature constantly to the main system. The idea is to have one admin who could track all reports from the main system and also could see temperature for each apartment separately. The tenant could see only his own apartment temperature.
The admin can administrate many buildings and one building can have many apartments and only one main smart heating system. For now I assume that one apartment can have only one thermometer. I could design db with sql but I have  to use NoSql and I don't have much experience designing that complex nosql db. 
I tried to design building collection but I think it is totally wrong. Should I have separateed collections for admin and tenant then for building and apartments, if yes then how to join it? Maybe someone know some example that I can take a look and have some ideas?
`{
    building: 1,
    address: 'address here',
    apartment: [
        { no : '1', floor:'0'},
        { no: '2', floor:'1'},
        { no: '3', floor:'2'}

```
],
thermometer : [
    { id : ObjectID('AAAA'), apartmentNo: '3'},         
    { id: ObjectID('F17C'), apartmentNo: '2'}, 
    { id: ObjectID('D2AA'), apartmentNo: '1'}

],
mainHeatingSys: [
    { thermId : ObjectID('AAAA')},         
    { thermId: ObjectID('F17C')},
    { thermId: ObjectID('D2AA')
    // etc
]
```

}`

Comment: There are *many* ways to design a document-oriented database, and so much will depend on your app's query needs. A very broad, opinion-soliciting type of question, and off-topic for StackOverflow . FYI your question is document-centric; there's no "nosql" schema to be had, since there are many flavors of NoSQL databases: key/value, document, column, graph.

Comment: Don't understand 'depend on your app's query needs'? I described what I need to have and what admin and tenant should get from db. If I can retrieve data by rule I defined (admin should get main systems and each apartment data, tenant only his own apartment data) I don't care which way I use unless it makes my application work more efficient. From this info that I provide you can easily create mysql database, so I thought that same is with NoSql.

Answer (score -1):

```
    var adminschema = new Schema({
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        email: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true }, lowercase: true },
        password: { type: String, required: true }
)}
    var heatingSystemschema = new Schema({
            number: { type: Number, required: true },
            building:[{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId}] //  objectid of building
 )}
    var buildingschema = new Schema({
        number: { type: Number, required: true },
        address: { type: String, required: true},
        appartment:[{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId}] // array of objectid of appartment
)}


    var appartment = new Schema({
        number: { type: Number, required: true },
        floor: { type: Number, required: true},
        thermometer:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId} // only one thermometer for each appartment so only objectId
)}

 var thermometer = new Schema({
            temprature: { type: string, required: true },

    )}
```

Just an idea how can u make ur database design

Comment: The question itself is very broad and opinion-soliciting, with no right answer. Just posting a sample schema isn't going to help, especially since you have no idea about the app's details. Also, the OP has admitted to not having any proficiency in this area, and wouldn't be able to tell what is good (or not good) about your schema. Not only that: You're showing code, vs general document-shaping (putting the proverbial cart before the horse).

Comment: @DavidMakogon: You are right we cannot provide him proper help but, i m just giving him idea of NOSQL database schema design as he told that he is not nobe he had worked with sql.

Comment: Ok right, so how will the OP, with no NoSQL experience, understand the issues with what you proposed? How is your schema handling multiple readings per thermostat? How are you storing the password (something not even part of the OP's question)? Why even choose a Document database over, say, a graph database,? What is the `Schema` class that you introduced with no hint as to the library it came from? What about single- vs multi-collection? I don't see how this answer helps.